# ReactJS - I can't reach a component inside in other by route

Tags: reactjs

I have an website with this structure:

```
<Header>
  <MenuPrincipal>
    <Home></Home>
  </MenuPrincipal>
</Header>
```

When I click on a logo in the Header, it isn't working, nothing is happening and I would like to access the Home component The `<Home>` component is inside of `<MenuPrincipal>`. The `<Header>` component is the parent component, how you can see in the structure above. How can I solve it?

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link,  } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './Home';

import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import { showBGImage } from './actions';

const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <h1>
              <Link onClick={showBGImage} className="home-link" to='/'>Mauro Bitar<br />
                <small className="home-link">arquiteto</small>
              </Link>
            </h1>
            <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Home />} />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default Header
```

Comment: are there console errors?

Comment: No there isn't any console error

Comment: Can you post the code for the `onClick={showBGImage}` event handler on `<Link/>`?

Answer (score 0):

`<BrowserRouter>` it's more like a history browser, you need to use Switch instead.

`import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'`

```
   const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <div>
            <h1>
              <Link onClick={showBGImage} className="home-link" to='/'>Mauro Bitar<br />
                <small className="home-link">arquiteto</small>
              </Link>
            </h1>
            <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Home />} />
          </div>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. Error message:
You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>

Comment: Surround the switch with the Router component. I've editing the code

Comment: It didn't work. The error message disapeared but it still the same. Nothing is appearing when I click on the logo. the only thing that changes is the url. for example when you have http://localhost:3000/portfolio and click on the logo it goes to  http://localhost:3000 bit it didn't show the home component.

Comment: I have discovered the root of the issue. I have replaced <Link> for <a> and now it is working succefully! Does anybody know why <Link> isn't working?